# How to automatically find I18N Violations

Tags: grails, internationalization, codenarc

Is there anyway to automatically find I18N violations in a Grails project? For example,

```
<td valign="top" class="name"><label for="enabled">Enabled:</label></td>
```

should be flagged because it's not using `<g:message>` to get the label value.

It would be nice if codenarc had a rule for this, but I don't think it does.

Comment: I review lots of code for i18n and l10n issues, and i just keep a few regular expressions handy.  Many are per-language.

Answer (score 1):

I have also looked for such a code quality test and have yet to find one.

Implementing this *should* be fairly trivial - if all text content in a GSP is required to be applied via  tags, your GSP should consist entirely of element nodes and no text nodes.

This crux of the problem is predominantly an XML issue: how do you check a set of XML documents and flag those that contain text nodes?

Assuming you can import `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.GrailsResourceUtils` in a codenarc rule you can use the `VIEWS_DIR_PATH` property to determine where all the GSP files live.

From there, the high level process you would need is:

1. Build a collection of all the GSP files in the application
2. For each file, load the content into an XML parser (Java has *plenty*) and check the node type for every node, flagging those files that contain text nodes

I appreciate that this is a very high level solution but conceptually it should work.